# sort array by value then by key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, data-structures

Suppose I have an array like so:

```
    $array => Array
    (
        [5] => 0.33
        [3] => 1             
        [2] => 0.33
    )
```

When I do `asort($array)` I get:

```
    $array => Array
    (
        [5] => 0.33
        [2] => 0.33
        [3] => 1             
    )
```

How can I sort it so that first the values get sorted and if they have same value then the keys get sorted, so that my final output would be:

```
   $array => Array
    (
        [2] => 0.33
        [5] => 0.33
        [3] => 1             
    )
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try [array_multisort](http://php.net/array_multisort) with a little trick

```
$array = array(
    0 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    7 => 1,
    2 => 0.33,
    5 => 0.33,
    6 => 0.33,
    1 => 0.33,
);
$array_keys = array_keys($array);
array_multisort($array, $array_keys);
$result = array_combine($array_keys, $array);
var_dump($result);
```